# Unable to create an intent in android studio

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello guys i'm having problems with my android studio, i'm having trouble creating an intent I don't know why i tried many ways but couldn't succeed, Every time i create it i get an error asking me to create a class or inner class. your help will be appreciated thanks.

[Here is my screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRrtX.png)

Comment: import the `intent` class ?

Comment: Please post your full code, not screenshots

Answer (score 0):

try to import this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
```